# How to make a drop down that include years and when a year is selected, it gets the people who registered in that year in a table using php

Tags: php, html

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Business Name</th>
            <th>Commencement Date</th>
            <th>Registered?</th>
            <th>Business Address</th>
            <th>Contact Details</th>
            <th>Contact Name</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <? 
        db_connect();
        $result=mysql_query("select * from hbs_participants_register ORDER BY hbs_id DESC");
        $num_result=mysql_num_rows($result);
        ?>
        <tr>
            <? 
            for ($i=0; $i<$num_result; $i++) {
                $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

                ?>
            <td width="10"><div align="left">
                    <?php echo $i+1; ?>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><div align="left">
                    <? echo $row['hbs_bus_name'] ?>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><div align="left">
                    <? echo $row['hbs_com_date'] ?>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><div align="left">
                    <? echo $row['hbs_bus_reg']; ?>
                    <br /> <strong><?php if (!empty($row['hbs_bus_regnumber'])) {
                        echo "Reg No. ".$row['hbs_bus_regnumber'];
                    }  else {} ?></strong>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><div align="left">
                    <? echo $row['hbs_bus_address']; ?>
                    <br />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><div align="left">
                    <? echo $row['hbs_email']; ?>
                    <br />
                    <? echo $row['hbs_phone']; ?>
                    <br />
                    <? echo $row['hbs_url']; ?>
                    <br />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><div align="left">
                    <? echo $row['hbs_contact_name']; ?>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="icon-cog"></i> <strong
                            style="font-size: 14px; padding: 5px 0px"> Manage</strong><span
                            class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a
                            href="../../print-busreg.php?hbs_id=<?php echo $row['hbs_id'];?>"
                            target="_blank"><i class="icon-list"></i> Full Details</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a
                            href="?w=plugins/HBS%202015/delete-busreg&hbs_id=<?php echo $row['hbs_id'];?>&amp;action=delete"
                            onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"><i
                                class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <? } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please consider explaining what you tried to do with your code, what is the expected result and why what you get is not what you expect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: @dgiugg I want to create a dropdown on this page that does it plus the years are stored in the database as timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work, assuming you are storing the data together with the year it was submitted. This is not the whole code you need, just the part which lets you select a year and get it from the Dbase.

```
<form method="get" action="page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
year:
    <select name="selectedYear">
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
  <option value="2001">2001</option>
  <option value="2002">2002</option>
  <option value="2003">2003</option>
  <option value="2004">2004</option>
   </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
 $year = $_GET['selectedYear'];
?>
```

So then you just get all the columns that contain that year:

```
mysql_query('"select * from hbs_participants_register WHERE year LIKE" . $year . "ORDER BY hbs_id DESC"');
```